# What icon intuitively represents making comparisons?

Tags: buttons, web-app, icons, interface, symbols

I want to make an app which involves repeatedly giving users two options and having them select the one they like better. Is there any icon or symbol which would intuitively represent this concept, which I could place next to the word "compare" on a navigation button? I'm wracking my brain and can't come up with anything, which suggests that there may not be a natural icon choice...

Comment: Hello, and welcome to UX.SE. Unfortunately, questions requesting icons for specific things are unlikely to be of much use to the community as a whole, so are closed as [not suitable for this site](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). A different resource you could check is [The Noun Project](https://thenounproject.com/) which contains a vast amount of free icons to browse through. Good luck, and feel free to post any future questions you may have!

Comment: Thank you! That site is actually exactly what I needed and didn't know I needed, and my first answer is also perfect. I'll be more careful in future though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A balance icon? :)

[image]

Or a very abstract one:

[image]

Comment: Actually... that's a brilliant idea. Why didn't I think of that myself? Thank you!

Comment: @SethSchmidt-O'Hainle - you didn’t think of it because there is no such thing as an intuitive icon that represents comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I found this "primary diff" icon from the KDE icon theme which uses a question mark to represent a choice between 2 options:

[image: primary-diff]

It is available [here](https://www.iconspng.com/image/26515/primary-diff) and is free for personal and commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your user group an A/B or Vs. icons might work.

[image]